# Turn random array into sequential array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, typing

I have a code snippet to display a typing effect of difference sentences but they are randomized..

It's for my personal website, but unfortunately I am not good with JS

```
let typed = "";
const element = document.querySelector(".typity");

function startType(pun, index) {
  if (index < pun.length) {
    typed += pun.charAt(index);
    element.innerHTML = typed;
    index++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      startType(pun, index);
    }, 50);
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.classList.add("highlight");
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      element.classList.remove("highlight");
      typed = "";
      element.innerHTML = typed;
      startType(getRandomPun(), 0);
    }, 2500);
  }
}

function getRandomPun() {
  const puns = [
    "A backwards poet writes inverse.",
    "A bicycle can't stand on its own because it's two-tired.",
    "A book just fell on my head. I've only got my shelf to blame.",
    "Yesterday I swallowed food coloring, I dyed a little on the inside."
  ];
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * puns.length);

  return puns[index];
}

startType(getRandomPun(), 0);
```

I would like them to be displayed 1 by 1 in order, and then back again to the 1st one

Comment: Put  `getRandomPun` in a for loop and pass loop variable to the function and use that in `puns[index]` as `index`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a **js liberary** known as **vara.js**

```html
<a href="https://codepen.io/umer2001uf/pen/yLLMPKG">here</a>
```